# How to align one view to the center of another view in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

[image]

In the above image, I have to align these dots (which are just empty View in XML) to the center of the icon which is above it

The below code is my recycler view which contains the view's

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/itemImage">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nestedRecyclerView"/>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and the above code is for icon

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_glucose"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
```

Now I need to align "NestedScrollView" to the center of "ImageView" so that the dots can align to the center of the icon.

if I set

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="nestedScrollView"
```

it will align it to the complete left, But i want it to be aligned to the center of the icon

How can i do that, any suggestion please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to directly align the NestedScrollView's left to the center of your ImageView, but there is a way.

You can align an empty View to the center of your ImageView (right to right side and left to left side of ImageView). Then, your NestedScrollView can simply align to this centered View, and by aligning RecyclerView to the left of NestedScrollView you will have the desired results.

Comment: I'm so glad google introduced constraint layout to simplify our lives. Who needs to center something anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simply give constraints as top to top of & bottom to bottom of the same view of which you want to align another view at center.

```
                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPrintKOT"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rgKOT"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rgKOT"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/rgKOT"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvPrintKOT"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    >
                </RadioGroup>
```